# Can't access webmin due to iptables missconfiguration

Tags: iptables, webmin

I installed webmin, but I cant access it because iptables blocks the connection. I have added the chain that webmin suggests right here: http://www.webmin.com/firewall.html

This is the result of iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Mar  8 07:45:32 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "Allow localhost communication" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "Allow localhost communication" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar  8 07:45:32 2016
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not much of an iptables professional myself, but i think that it moves through the rules from top to bottom until it finds one that matches the incoming packet. The first matching rule is then applied to this packet. I think the rule

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

tells iptables to REJECT all communication. Move your rule above it, so that it gets applied before this rule, and you might be fine.
Let me know if it worked, if it doesn't I will ask a colleague who knows iptables better.